# How to access double nested Json field with Gson without creating additional classes

Tags: java, json, gson

So i have the JSON from below and I am trying to parse it with Gson Library.

```
{"id":"1",
"categoes":{
    "cars":"toyota",
    "airplanes":"airplane",
    "other_types":
        {"ships":{
                  "ice":"icebreakers"
                 }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get only the "ice" field key and value without creating just one Java class.

How can I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: which classes you already have? how do you attempted to solve the issue? what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gson has a predefined class called `JsonObject` which allows you to get elements from a JSON String. This is one (not very pretty) way to do it:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject jobj = gson.fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);
        System.out.println(jobj.getAsJsonObject("categoes").getAsJsonObject("other_types").getAsJsonObject("ships").get("ice").getAsString());
```